# How to use a reference variable in a C++ class?

Tags: c++

I want to have a reference data member in a class, but I do not want to initialize it in the constructor.

How could I do this?

Comment: Note that this is *often* a poor idea. It means (among other things) that objects of the class can't be assigned or copied.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: No assignment makes sense - you can't change the reference - but copying should be possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is not possible, you *have to* initialize reference data members inside ctor initialization list. If you really have to do something like this, use a pointer to the data member instead of reference. Initialize pointer to `NULL` in ctor and then initialize it correctly whenever you want.

Comment: If the data is critical to the class (so much so that you'd want to index based on it), the class probably should have its own copy of that data, as a member.

Answer (score 2):

You must initialize it in the constructor (**only** through initializer-list), since that's the attribute of a reference-variable (references must be initialized).

You may initialize it to some static/global variable by keeping it inialized by default parameter.

```
YourClass::YourClass(int& ref = _SomeGlobalVar) : m_RefInClass(ref){}
```

But you wont be able to re-initialize it further.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, this is often a poor idea, if a reference is required somewhere - there is usually a solid reason as to why.

If there is a specific reasoning for what you're doing though, you may want to [have a look at Null Object Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

You can make a null object that throws some sort of 'not implemented' exception, or does nothing at all. You are still going to have to initialize your member variable in the **initializer list**, but now at least you have some flexibility to make changes in the future.